# Two fingers on trackpad with Qt app

Tags: macos, qt, trackpad

I'm currently trying to make our Qt application react as it should when using the "two fingers" feature of the trackpad on Mac. As of now, when working in a QGraphicsScene, if the user use "two fingers" the view is zoomed which is not what I want. I want the scene to scroll in the right direction.

I looked at the GestureType and tried to grab the gestures and use custom event with them. That part works fine.

However, it seems that when using the "two fingers", all I'm catching is a pinch gesture instead of what should be a pan gesture (I think). From what i found here http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/214/358/view , it should work with the two touch points, but it doesn't seems to.

So is there any way to detect the "two fingers" from the trackpad ?

I'm currently working with QT 4.8.2 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.